# Xmlhttprequest returns 401 on phonegap/android application

Tags: android, xml, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I want to access to the service web via my PhoneGap/android application with xmlhttprequest, but the code below returns "Status is 401".

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                   request.open("GET","http://www.mysite.fr/api/customers/2",true);
                   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   alert("Status is "+request.status);
                           if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0){
   response  = request.responseXML.documentElement;
   itemDescription = response.getElementsByTagName('lastname')[0].firstChild.data;
   alert ( itemDescription );
                           }
                   }
                   request.send();
```

Can anyone help me explaining the error or offering me a solution?

Comment: Well 401 is the unauthorized error. Does the site require you to login?

Comment: no, the site doesn't require a login, but the web service require a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your website is created by prestashop, so to access the webservice using Xmlhttprequest, the request.open should be like this:

```
request.open("GET","http://www.mysite.fr/api/customes/2?PHP_AUTH_USER="+PHP_AUTH_USER+"&ws_key="+ws_key,true);
```

with: `PHP_AUTH_USER=""  and ws_ke=key_generated_by_the_webservice`