# PhoneGap and Joomla web service

Tags: javascript, android, xml, cordova, joomla1.5

I want to retrieve data from web service that (returns XML) of my Joomla web site. I use PhoneGap Android. Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hi fekria. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you give us some more information? Is your question related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431877/xmlhttprequest-returns-401-on-phonegap-android-application[link]

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376665/phonegap-and-restful-web-service[link]

Comment: thank you, I have tried the second code, but no results

Comment: I follow this link in activating my web service aide.mashupxfeed.com/installation-configuration/joomla/… but I don't know the url to reach the web service of joomla(xml page)

Comment: please, have you any idea about this?, I don't find solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer
[PhoneGap XML Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306394/phonegap-xml-parser)
It suggests that you use javascript to retrieve xml from phonegap.

Comment: yes, but now the problem that I want to show the xml of joomla. After activating web service of joomla, I need to see the xml page of my web site joomla. So, I don't find what I will add to the url of the web site joomla to show the xml of it(for example in prestashop, you will add url of site/api), please have you any idea??

Answer (score 0):

so you having php running at the server and javascript in mobile device. there are various jquery(javascript library) functions that can ask the server for some data (XML or json), which then can be further parsed according to the requirements. google for the functions..

Answer (score 0):

look at this link http://forum.joomla.fr/showthread.php?123456-webservices/page2

In the response number 8 there is:

"Ca c'est souvent le probleme des WebServices car ca dépend de la techno utilisée coté client (Quel langage ? PHP, Java, .Net ... !?! quelle API ? ... )

Maintenant pour l'appel, il faut preciser selon ton API XML d'appel :
- l'url d'entrée des appels Webservices Joomla : http://www.site.fr/xmlrpc/index.php
- la methode de ton webService a appeler : ex : monwebservice.getInfo
(par exemple si ton webservice est un plugin dont le nom est (dans le XML) : 
et que la fonction a appeler est (dans le .php) : 'monwebservice.getInfo' )"

I hope it help you.

Comment: I follow this link in activating my web service http://aide.mashupxfeed.com/installation-configuration/joomla/activation-xml-rpc but I don't know the url to reach the web service of joomla(xml page)

Comment: thank you, it help me, but the problem now when I accede to the web service, it show me this page Aucune information de style ne semble associée à ce fichier XML. L'arbre du document est affiché ci-dessous.

Comment: Aucune information de style ne semble associée à ce fichier XML. L'arbre du document est affiché ci-dessous.
      <methodResponse><fault><value><struct><member><name>faultCode</name><value><int>105</int></value></member><member><name>faultString</name><value><string>XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1</string></value></member></struct></value></fault></methodResponse>I'm installing com_jmonitoring.zip but the problem persist, please have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

we did a more recent and stable RPC-JSON(Dojo & SMD compatible) adapter for Joomla and any other SQL & PHP based system . You simply pass queries and nested schemas which can have PHP functions in top. security is done by b&w listings.

its free, Dual(GPL&Custom)  and part of our mobile-app-ide : xapp-studio.com (download the Joomla plug).

the actual work is done by another project of us : xapp-php.com which turns out as universal PHP gateway.

the JS part however can be done by any JSON RPC capable library.